Java textbox has wrong bounds
I am learning Java, and, while trying to create a textbox, I expected the textbox to be 100 pixels wide and 30 pixels tall. Instead, it fills the entire window.
The code
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Main extends Frame implements ActionListener{
    TextField tf;
    Main(){
        tf = new TextField();
        tf.setBounds(0, 30, 100, 30);
        Button b = new Button("Click me");
        b.setBounds(0, 60, 100, 30);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);
        add(tf);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        tf.setText("Thank you");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Main();
    }
}

Tried to get textbox to be 100x30. Instead, it fits the entire window.

Don't use awt, use swing. No one uses awt for window components since swing replaced it 20+ years ago.

And if you're inclined to use absolute positioning via setLocation, don't.  Use layout managers.

I recommend using the Oracle Java Tutorials to learn.  Specifically https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/.  They are not always the best resource for newer Java language and platform features, but they are still better than typical stuff you find via google search.  (Not naming any culprits ... )

textbox - what is a textbox. I'm not aware of that Java class. The default layout manager will override your size.

The default layout for a Frame is BorderLayout.
It's javadoc tells it anchors and stretches components.
For an absolute positioning like in your case:
    ...
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

Frame's LayoutManager would be null
